# SP10 Workflow - Reassign task & Request Change (not assigning to submitter)

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have just started using Workflows for several people approving a document.

I really like the ability of being able to request a change or reassign the task, but they don't seem to be working.

When the approver uses one of these functions, they can finish the process but then nothing happens.

The submittor or person the task has been reassigned to, do not receive any details that something needs to be done.

Am I missing something to make this work? Normal approvals and rejections work absolutely fine.